# How to avoid UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with top level try/catch only?

Tags: node.js

Ideally i hope my app only have top level try/catch, most of the exceptions just bubble up. But with this you'll get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

```
function example() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("test reject");
  });
}

try {
  example().then(r => console.log(`.then(${r})`));
} catch (e) {
  console.error(`try/catch(${e})`);
}
```

My question is, instead of putting another .catch after .then, is there a way to get around ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can either await your promise (inside an async function but can be made top level), so that your catch block can catch the exception or create a global `unhandledpromise` handler.

```js
function example() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject("test reject");
    });
  }
  
  (async () => {
  try {
    await example()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`try/catch(${e})`);
  }
})()
```

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
  console.log('unhandledRejection', error.message);
});
```

Comment: if this is in controller, can your solution still work ？